# Radius of convergence of sum of two complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^n(z-2+i)^n}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(1+in)(z-2+i)^n=I_1+I_2$$
My first idea was to examine radius of convergence for each series, but I don't know if it is a good idea. If so, I'm struggling with first series.
My attempt:

For $I_2$ we have:
$$
r=\frac{1}{\lambda}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|}
$$
We calculate for $I_2$:
$$\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|=\frac{(1+in)(z-2+i)^n}{(1+i(n+1))(z-2+i)^{n+1}}=\frac{1+in}{1+i(n+1)(z-2+i)}$$
Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{1+in}{1+i(n+1)}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{1+in+i-i}{1+in+i}\right|=$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left|1-\frac{1}{1+in+i}\right|=1$$
Hence $|z-2+i|=1$ is area of convergence for second term.

Comment: You could begin by setting $w = z-2+i$ and save a lot of writing.

Comment: This is a Laurent series about $2-i$. The first series converges *outside* some radius of convergence (because of the inverted argument), while the second converges inside another radius of convergence. Added together, the whole Laurent series converges in the annulus between the radii of convergence.